# Chrome renders TABLE TD with one pixel width instead of zero pixels

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

Before submitting a Bug to Chrome I am wondering, if I am missing something here:

```
<html>
<head>
  <style>
  table{
    border-spacing: 0;
  }
  table td {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><div></div></td>
      <td>
        <span>Test</span>
      </td>
      <td><div></div></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

This is a super simple TABLE. Chrome renders the first and last TD with 1 pixel width, which IMHO should be 0 pixels. FF and IE both render 0 pixels. If you remove the DIV from first TD, the last TD renders with 2 pixels. If you remove the DIV from the last TD the first TD stays at 1 pixel.

What am I thinking wrong?

Comment: I don't see the problem in my Chrome http://jsfiddle.net/imtheman/wswfchLo. Also, you might try `border-collapse: collapse;` for the table, that might make it more consistent for you. http://jsfiddle.net/imtheman/wswfchLo/1/

Comment: Well not in my Chrome (36.0.1985.143), on Mac and on Window both, the TD (and respectivly the DIVs inside) render with 1x width (check you Chrome Inspector). Are you *sure* you see 0 pixels there?